# How I can create a button for save a image with Javascript or any Javascript framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, save

I would like save with a button a generated picture. I see the fastest solution is `JavaScript`, probably `JQuery` or any framework.

My application generate a `img` label, for example:

```
<img src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...(it's very long)"/>
```

The many problem is the `src` attribute because change for my application, first I need catch the URL of this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `download` attribute in HTML. If the img `src` is automatically generated, you could use the script below to put it in the `href`:

```js
$('#save').prop('href', $('img').prop('src'));
```

```html
<img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png"/><br/>
<a id='save' download>Save</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My problem is the URL. My application generate the URL and I need catch its